# Can any one make this embeded video auto play?

Tags: video, embedded-video

Can any one make this embeded video auto play?

```
<object id="vbbplayer" width="425" height="344" >
 <param name="movie" value="http://www.videobb.com/player/player.swf?setting=aHR0cDovL3d3dy52aWRlb2JiLmNvbS9wbGF5ZXJfY29udHJvbC9zZXR0aW5ncy5waHA/dj05QkhzR2pYdkFEb0ImZW09VFJVRQ==" ></param>
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" ></param>
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
 <embed src="http://www.videobb.com/player/player.swf?setting=aHR0cDovL3d3dy52aWRlb2JiLmNvbS9wbGF5ZXJfY29udHJvbC9zZXR0aW5ncy5waHA/dj05QkhzR2pYdkFEb0ImZW09VFJVRQ==&em=TRUE" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: potential spam link, that is, using SO to advertise link

Comment: It is not mine, i don't want you to enter the site, i want only the code that make it auto play.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different player, like [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/).  This vbbplayer looks likes like the forgotten project of a summer intern.